# Read last input first, when reading through scanner

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

```
Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
while(true){
    int X = in.nextInt();
    System.out.println(X);
}
```

The above code can only read the numbers in the order i entered them.
Eg: 1 2 3 4
These numbers will be read as
1
2
3
4

I want them to be read in a reverse order. I can't find any methods to do so.

Comment: so read them into an array, reverse the array, and off you go...

Comment: i know that, but is there a different way, without using any other variables...

Comment: `I want them to be read in a reverse order`. Can you describe this behavior? Let's say that the user enters the first input as `1`. What should happen next according to you? You want to tweak the JVM?

Comment: You should mention that in the question. Explicit is the mark of a good question!

Comment: @ChetanKinger I am continuously entering each number after a space. The scanner will read each as a different integer, it's a simple doubt.

Comment: @sanal You should change `I want them to be read in a reverse order` to `I want to reverse the order of the input read`. It's not a very simple question until you make this change.

Comment: Actually, I want to read them in reverse order. I thought there might be some simple solution that i didn't know of.

Comment: @sanal In that case, we are back to square one. `I want to read them in reverse order`. Can you describe this behavior? Let's say that the user enters the first input as 1. What should happen next according to you? As already pointed out by Marc, why do you want to do such a thing?

Comment: @ChetanKinger Have u tried the page www.codingame.com , I recently found out that page. In the easy section of games, the third one "The Descent". I am trying to solve that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it "without any other variables" recursively:

```
public static void revNumbers(Scanner in) {
    if(!in.hasNextInt())
        return;
    int X = in.nextInt();
    revNumbers(in);
    System.out.println(X);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    revNumbers(new Scanner(System.in));
}
```

Comment: "reading" in a reverse order and "printing" in a reverse order are two different things I guess. @sanal, did you want to print them in the reverse order?

Comment: I did wanted to read them in reverse order. Thought there was some method to do so that i didn't know.